# No module named _struct ironpython

Tags: ironpython

I've trying to use IronPython 2.7.4 with .net 3.5. I've create a new project and added needed references:

```
IronPython.dll
IronPython.Modules.dll
Microsoft.Dynamic.dll
Microsoft.Scripting.dll
Microsoft.Scripting.Core.dll
```

Then in my c# code i'm using a preparation script to define lib path

```
string preparationstring = "import sys\nsys.path.append(r\"C:\\Python27\\Lib\")";
```

Then i'm trying to execute script which is using "struct" module and getting an error 
No module named _struct

How can i resolve it?

Answer (score 2):

It's strange, but IronPython.Modules.dll does'not automatically copied to the bin directory. After i've got manually copied it everything starts to be ok.